# Modify network state in testing

Tags: android, testing, networking

I'm writing instrumented unit test for an android app. Right now I want to test a function that returns the network type of the current connection.

In order to test it, I would like a way to automate the shifting in available network type when using emulators.

Is there anyway that I can set up the emulator from within the testing script?

**I am thinking something like**

```
@Test
public void UsingEDGE() {
    emulatorHandler.setNetworkType(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE);
    String connectivityState = deviceInformation.networkStatus(appContext);

    assertEquals("EDGE", connectivityState);


}
```

Is there such an "emulatorHandler" or other means to construct this kind of test?